# Deleting wlm logs

Tags: memory, datastage

I'm having space trouble in my DataStage machine. I've seen the directory /opt/IBM/InformationServer/Server/DSWLM/logs is accumulating a lot of wlm logs (4 Gb) but I'm not sure if it is safe to delete these logs.

I've tried to free space deleting unnecesary jobs and the jobs that I keep in my repository purges its logs older than 35 days. This not solved my problem.

Thanks for your time and your help!

Answer (score 0):

It is safe. You should first shut down the DataStage Workload manager (WLM) before deleting those files. Then when you start the WLM again, a new log will be started.

Start/Stop WLM

On UNIX and Linux:

change directory to /opt/IBM/InformationServer/Server/DSWLM
to start WLM: nohup ./startwlm.sh
to stop WLM: nohup ./stopwlm.sh

On Windows:

change directory to C:\IBM\InformationServer\Server\DSWLM
to start WLM: startwlm.cmd
to stop WLM: stopwlm.cmd

While you're at it, you might as well change the max log size.

The LoggingRollingSize parameter is in the parameter section of file: \Server\DSWLM\dist\lib\wlm.config.xml
You can use a text editor to edit this file.
Example:

Hope that helps.